Determine the Galois group of $x^{p+1} - sx -t = 0$ over $F(s,t)$
Assume $F$ is a field of character $p$, and $s$, $t$ are indeterminates.
I wonder why the Galois group of $x^{p+1} - sx -t = 0$ over $F(s,t)$ is isomorphic to the linear fractional group of maps $x \rightarrow \frac{ax + b}{cx+d}$, and $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, $ad-bc \neq 0$.
If the polynomial is $x^{p} - sx -t$, then we can easily get the roots. And I'm also curious about the Galois group of $x^{n}-sx-t = 0$ over $F(s,t)$ where n is a positive integer. Are there any reference for this question?
Thank you in advance.

I found the paper 'Galois group of an equation $X^{n} - aX + b =0 $' written by
Uchida and published in Tohoku Math.J. 22 (1970).

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
